# tuple Конвертация

Tags: python, aiogram, tuple

я пытался конвертировать данные из базы данных при отправке сообщения получал

> ['textindatabase']

а нужно что-бы текст был без скобок и кавычек вот код:

```
def get_data(self) -> tuple:
    res = self.cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT 'data' FROM 'gamedev'").fe-tchall()
    return [i[0] for i in res]
```

Comment: почему tuple если вы возвращаете list ? во-вторых, print отражает структуру данных, показывая вам, что  это список, содержащий строку. Чтоб вывести саму строку, напишите `print(lst[0])`

Comment: потому что я использую базу данных для бота и так легче я не пользуюсь принтом и способ не робочий(выводит название столбца)

Comment: тогда, что такое "выведение" ?